# Trying to use CKQuerySubscription on a shared record

Tags: swift, swiftui, notifications, cloudkit, ckshare

as the title says, I'm trying to subscribe for changes using CKQuerySubscription, the subscription is correctly created (present on CK dashboard) but I'm not receiving a notification on my phone (not simulator)

Here is the code:

```
`func createGroup(name: String) async {
        guard let userID = PersistenceManager.shared.fetchUserInfo()?.userRecordID
        else { return }

        loadingNewGroup = true
        
        let group = ExpensesGroup.create(name: name, userID: userID)
        await PersistenceManager.shared.context.perform {
            try! PersistenceManager.shared.context.save()
        }
        
        self.selectedExpensesGroup = group

        await PersistenceManager.shared.createShare(group)
        
        await createQuerySubscription(group)
        
        loadingNewGroup = false
        sheetToShow = nil
        sheetToShow = .manageShare
    }
    
    func createQuerySubscription(_ group: ExpensesGroup) async {
        let privateDB = PersistenceManager.shared.ckContainer.privateCloudDatabase

        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        
        let shareSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "cloudkit.share", predicate: predicate, subscriptionID: "\(group.id ?? "")", options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordDeletion, .firesOnRecordUpdate])
        
        let notification = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
        notification.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
        
        shareSubscription.notificationInfo = notification
        
        let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [shareSubscription])
        
        operation.modifySubscriptionsResultBlock = { result in
            print(result)
        }
        
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        
        privateDB.add(operation)
    }
    `
```

I tried using CD_ExpensesGroup (It's the actual recordName) instead of "cloudkit.share" same result.

I put a print("notification") in appdelegate func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

Comment: You need to work on `AppDelegate`.

Comment: @ElTomato can you elaborate?...